# Kotlin Android Studio - Use HTML tags inside strings

Tags: android, html, string, kotlin

I have to use some HTML tags inside a string.
The problem is that I can't use `Html.FromHtml` because the string is in strings.xml file for multi-language, so I should use the tags directly, but only `</b>`, `</i>` and `<u>` works and I need `</h5>` and `</p>`.

This is the string:

```
<string name="test">This is a test</string>
```

Comment: Html.fromhtml() doesn't support all html tags

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly, the problem is that I can't use it because I need to insert HTML tags inside strings.xml, not in the Kotlin code

Comment: you can use CDATA for  html tags inside strings.xml

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CDATA in strings.xml to get all supported html tags.

```
<string name="stringName1"><![CDATA[<html>Some Text<h5>Some H5 Text</h5></html>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

In main activity

Use
textviewid.setText(html.fromHtml(getString(R.String.stringname)));
to get the data in the textview